# Scaling JFrame chart based on y values

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm plotting the results of an analysis with JFrame, but since the values range from 10e-7 to 10e-2, the plot looks like flat.

[image]

The X axis is fine, but I'd like the Y axis to scale based on the values I'm currently plotting, for the plot to look like this (don't mind multiple plots and the different grid, it's just a plot example).

[image]

The portion of code I'm currently using to plot is the following:

```
ChartPanel plot = TransientSolutionViewer.solutionChart(solution);
    plot.restoreAutoRangeBounds();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(graphName);
            frame.add(plot);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            frame.setExtendedState(6);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What library are you using to do your plotting?

Comment: @matt I'm using JFreeChart, but I already found a way to scale the axis, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how to do it. Since I'm using JFreeChart to plot, a way to do it is

```
plot.getChart().getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(PLOT_LOWERBOUND);
plot.getChart().getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setUpperBound(PLOT_UPPERBOUND);
```